# cmake kdev-executebrowser plugin for kdevelop

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, kde-plasma, kdevelop

I am trying to install kdev-executebrowser from https://github.com/KDE/kdev-executebrowser into kdevelop.

So I cloned the plugin from git hub and tried to cmake and got an error (please check the quote below).

I can't figure how how to solve this. Please help 
I also attached my system info and hope it might help

[System Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs2aG.png)

> ```
> waleed@waleed-Dell-System-Inspiron-N411Z:~/Downloads/kdev-executebrowser$
> ```
>
> cmake .
>   -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>   -- Detecting C compile features
>   -- Detecting C compile features - done
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
>   -- Detecting CXX compile features
>   -- Detecting CXX compile features - done                                                                                              CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:111
>   (message):
>   ERROR: cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake not found in
>   /home/waleed/.kde/share/apps;/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/apps;/usr/share/kde4/apps               Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!                                                                                           See also
>   "/home/waleed/Downloads/kdev-executebrowser/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Comment: Thank you. It worked and also generated another error to install, did the same thing, installed kdevplatform-dev and it got installed successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FindKDE4Internal.cmake

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=FindKDE4Internal.cmake&mode=exactfilename&suite=saucy&arch=any

The missing package is usually `kdelibs5-dev`.